# asp.net Webservice returns XML instead of JSON

Tags: iphone, asp.net, ios, xcode, web-services

I am writing a webservice for my IPhone application. The Webservice should return the "HelloWorld" in JSON but it returns XML. I don't know why

I have the following Webservice

```
    [ScriptService]
    public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "HelloWorld";
        }
    }
```

and following in Xcode

```
- (IBAction)parseButton:(id)sender {

NSString *urlString = @"http://217.160.223.254/Webdienst2/Service1.asmx/HelloWorld";

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSError *errorReturned = nil;
NSURLResponse *theResponse =[[NSURLResponse alloc]init];
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&theResponse error:&errorReturned];

if (errorReturned) 
{
    NSLog(@"Error");
}
else 
{
    NSString *retVal = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];  

    NSLog(@"%@", retVal);
}
```

Comment: -1 you should share your solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the Content-Type request header to `application/json`:

```
[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSError *errorReturned = nil;
```

Comment: i tried that already but he still returns XML. I updated my questions

Comment: found the solution. Updated my Question. THX For help